# Unable to understand this lemma

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The lemma is from the book *Discrete Mathematics for computer scientists and mathematicians* by *Joe L Mott, Abraham Kendal, and Theodore P Baker*

> Suppose $x$ and $m$ are positive integers and $r$ is the smallest positive integer for which there exist integers $c$ and $d$ such that $r = cx + dm$, then $r = gcd(x, m)$

This lemma doesn't make sense to me. Clearly, if all $x, m, c, d$ are integers then $r$ has to be greater than them, then how can $r$ be their gcd? Even if $c$ and $d$ are negative, what even is the point of doing so? The whole thing seems really bizzare. The proof is even more bizarre though

> Proof: Suppose $x = pr + q$, where $0 \le q < r$ then, $q = x - pr = x - p(cx + dm) = (1-pc)x + (-pd)m$

> Since $r$ is the smallest positive integer of this form, and $0 \le q < r$, it must be that $q = 0$ which is to say r divides x

I don't understand how they managed to derive $q = 0$ from this. If anyone is able to explain it more clearly, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not more clearly, just more words: They showed that $q$ is the sum of an integer multiple of $x$ (namely, $1-pc$ times $x$) and an integer multiple of $m$ (namely, $-pd$ times $m$). If $q$ **were** a positive integer, then it would be an element of the set of positive integers writable as sum of an integer multiple of $x$ and an integer multiple of $m$. By definition, $r$ is the smallest element of that set. Hence we'd need to have $q\ge r$, but certainly $q<r$. - We conclude that $q$ is not a positive integer. Given its possible range, $0\le q<r$, the only remaining possibility is that $q=0$.

Comment: It shows that $q$ is also an integer of the form $cx+dm$, but it is less than $r$.  The only choice left is for $q=0$.

Comment: Since $\,c,d\,$ can be negative integers, $r$ does not need to be greater than $x$ and $m$. For example, if $x=8$ and $m=9$, then there exist $c=8$ and $d=-7$ such that $r=1=cx+dm\,.$

Comment: I guess that [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is the point. A good point at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of understanding what the lemma is trying to achieve, think about what the values of $cx + dm$ are - they're linear combinations of $x$ and $m$. If $x$ and $m$ were, say, two denominations of poker chips, then $cx + dm$ represents the values we can generate from having $c$ of the first chip and $d$ of the second.

If $c$ and $d$ were strictly non-negative, then we would be looking at a [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) (also known as a McNugget problem). However, the lemma does *not* put this restriction on $c$ and $d$, so in this case it's possible to *owe* a certain number of each denomination, in order to expand the range of possible values.

So, for example, if $x = 6$ and $m = 9$, then we can achieve the following values (among others):

| $c$ | $d$ | $cx + dm$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $1$ | $15$ |
| $0$ | $3$ | $27$ |
| $1$ | $-2$ | $3$ |
| $-3$ | $-2$ | $-30$ |

The lemma then states that the smallest positive such value you can achieve is the GCD of $x$ and $m$. So with my example, you can find a linear combination to make $cx + dm = \gcd(6, 9) = 3$ (which I did in the table), but you *cannot* make $cx + dm = 1$ or $cx + dm = 2$.

The proof comes by applying the division algorithm - we know that for any positive integers $a$ and $b$ we can always write $a = lb + k$ for some non-negative integer $l$ and $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, b - 1\}$ (i.e. "$a$ divided by $b$ gives $l$, with remainder $k$").

Applying that to the division of $x$ by $r$ gives $x = pr + q$. We rearrange that to get $q = x - pr$, then substitute $r = cx + dm$ to get $q = x - p(cx + dm) = (1 - pc)x + (-pd)m$. This is *also* a linear combination of $x$ and $m$, but we have assumed that $r$ is the smallest positive such value, and we have constructed $q$ to be in the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, r - 1\}$, and removing the positive values from that set leaves $q = 0$ as the only possibility.

But then that means $x = pr + q = pr$ thus demonstrating that $r$ divides $x$. Similarly you can prove that $r$ divides $m$, making $r$ a common divisor of $x$ and $m$, and the final step is proving that $r$ must be the greatest such common divisor, which you do by taking $c$ to be any common divisor and showing that $c$ must divide $r$.

What's the point? This is an extremely important result known as [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which underpins a huge amount of number theory. In particular, it forms part of the proof of the Chinese remainder theorem, which is fundamental to things like the RSA encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

About the lemma: if $c$ and $d$ can be negative, then the lemma is correct.

About the proof: since $q=(1-pc)x+(-pd)m$, $q$ verifies the kind of equation that $r$ verifies: a linear combination of $x$ and $m$ with integer coefficients. But we have supposed that $r$ is the smallest positive integer that verifies this. As $0\le q \lt r$, this implies $q=0$.